# Remove .html from the homepage but not from folders within within that website

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to remove the `.html` from my landing page, an example would isntead of `domain.com/contact.html` it would be `domain.com/contact` while at the same time keeping the `.html` for all the folders within the website, so `domain.com/components/file.html` would stay as a `.html`..

So in other words redirect for the landing page, but not for all the other files on my server..

This is the code I'm currently using to remove the `.html` but it also removes it for all the other directories as well.

```
#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Would anyone have any advice on this matter?

Thank you.

Comment: Cross-site post: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109680/htacess-remove-html-from-the-homepage-but-not-from-folders-within-within-tha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.[^\/]*)$ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: did you mean when you request mydomain.com/contact.html it doesn't remove .html?

Comment: clearing cache doesn't help... I mean when I go to `mydomain.com/contact` or `mydomain.com/login` that it removes the `.html` and shows the page. with your code above it says `404 error not found`

Comment: ok , i understand you , you need to redirect internal to .html , i will update with full code

Comment: glad to help , wish you all the best